# Jenkins node property 'usage' and how to update with python

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have looked many places for how to set the usage property in jenkins using python. I looked at the create_node but there is no parameter for the usage or that I have found. I also looked at reconfig_node but looking at the current xml I didn't see a usage field in the xml to be updated for usage. So not sure how to update or create nodes where I can set the usage property.

I know how to set this manually but I currently have a python script to create the node but the usage is always set to 'Use this node as much as possible'.

So I'm looking for a way to set the usage for a node when creating a node or just update after it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `config.xml`, the usage is stored using the `<mode></mode>` tags. The two usage modes are:

1. `NORMAL` - "Use this node as much as possible"
2. `EXCLUSIVE` - "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node"

For the Jenkins python API `create_node` method, I think you need to look at the `exclusive` parameter:

1. `exclusive=False` - `NORMAL` - "Use this node as much as possible"
2. `exclusive=True` - `EXCLUSIVE` - "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node"

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear what that property was.  Would be nice if they labeled it usage.  :-)   Let me give that a try.  Thanks

Comment: I did the create_node but had to use False to get it to set to "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node".  So is that something setup on the Jenkins side or you just mixed up the True/False?

Comment: From the [docs](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.create_node) :  "**exclusive** – Use this node for tied jobs only, `bool`", with a default of `exclusive=False`. From the [source](https://github.com/pycontribs/jenkinsapi/blob/master/jenkinsapi/jenkins.py#L314): `:param exclusive: tied to specific job, boolean`